# Break Completable Future's then apply chain

Tags: java, completable-future

I have many calls that look like these. The problem is that next call fully depends on previous one. If there isn't any conversations fetching messages from them makes no sense so i just want break this chain. I read few topics with Holger's answers but I feel I still don't fully understand this. Could someone give me some examples based on this code?

```
public CompletableFuture<Set<Conversation>> fetchConversations(List<Information> data, String sessionId)
{
    return myservice
        .get(prepareRequest(data, sessionId))
        .thenApply(HtmlResponse::getDocument)
        .thenApply(this::extractConversationsFromDocument);
}
public CompletableFuture<Elements> fetchMessagesFromConversation(String Url, String sessionId)
{
    return mySerice
        .get(prepareRequest(url, sessionId))
        .thenApply(HtmlResponse::getDocument)
        .thenApply(this::extractMessageFromConversation);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like something you'd do with the `CompletableFuture`. Presumably, one of the chained continuations will receive a list of conversations. If that list is empty, just return/exit/stop. You could end up returning an empty `Set` for example.

Comment: Yeah but how can I stop that? There is about 20 chained-methods, each one depends on previous and every each returns next Stage without any validation. So i have to implement that, these chains goes trough 3 classes and the end the final method also returns CompletableFuture (i guess really final consumer is not implemented yet). I also heard that  just breaking chain at some point isn't good practice but Im not sure about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throwing an exception from any of your chain steps will skip all subsequent steps: none of the `thenApply()` callbacks will be called and the future will be resolved with the exception occurred. You can use it to break your chain. For example, consider the following code:

```
public CompletableFuture<Set<Conversation>> fetchConversations(List<Information> data, String sessionId) {
    return myservice
            .get(prepareRequest(data, sessionId))
            .thenApply(HtmlResponse::getDocument)
            .thenApply(value -> {
                if (checkSomeCondition(value)) 
                    throw new CompletionException(new CustomException("Reason"));
                return value;
            })
            .thenApply(this::extractConversationsFromDocument)
            .exceptionally(e -> {
                // the .thenApply(this::extractConversationsFromDocument) step 
                // was not executed
                return Collections.emptySet(); //or null
            });
}
```

You can add a step in which you check the value returned from the previous step, and, depending on some condition, throw an exception.

Then after the last `.thenApply` you can add an `exceptionally` handler and return an empty `Set`, `null` or something else as an unsuccessful result.

You can also omit the `exceptionally` handler. In this case you have to catch the exception at the end of the chain, where you finally call `.get()`:

```
try {
    Set<Conversation> conversations = fetchConversations(data, id).get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // handle the InterruptedException
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // handle the ExecutionException
    // e.getCause() is your CustomException or any other exception thrown from the chain
}
```

Comment: And in case I don't care for handling this exception can I just omit handle / exceptionally blocks?

Comment: Yes, but you should keep in mind that final `.get()` may throw this exception